# How to remove accidentally set file association

Tags: windows, file-association

I downloaded a zip file and accidentally made it open with Wordpad. How do I change the file association back to the default, with no association at all?

Comment: Is this about ZIP files? Or perhaps about what is contained therein?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can set it back to blank at least not from the gui interface. You can change it to something else though. Go to Control Panel/Programs/Default Programs/Set Associations. Click on the extension, and then click "Change program".

[image: Set Associations]